# HttpClient 4.4.1 not support TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I would like to connect to page and get response. I have cert at server in file with truststores. Other page work great, but not host=ebok.duon.pl

I use Java 7 and HttpClient:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot support TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers
at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(CipherSuiteList.java:92)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLSocketImpl.java:2374)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:369)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:415)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117)
```

I checked at Java 8 but is the same.

a few code:

```
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    context.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

    HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(host, 443, "https");

    try {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts
                .custom()
                .useTLS()
                .build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslContext,
                new String[]{"TLSv1", "TLSv1.0", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2", "SSLv3"},
                new String[]{"TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"},
                null);

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig
                .custom()
                .setRedirectsEnabled(false)
                .setConnectTimeout(60000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(10000)
                .setSocketTimeout((60000)
                .build();


        this.httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
                .create()
                .setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36")
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .setSslcontext(sslContext)
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
                .build();


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

how can I fix / around ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue with HttpClient but with the JRE you are running under

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_***AES_256***_CBC_SHA < That indicates that the server is attempting to negotiate using AES-256/CBC as the cipher mechanism.

If you are running a standard Oracle JRE/JDK, you will be required to install the JCE policy files to enable encryption strength greater than AES 192-bit.